# Packet length mismatch while using libpcap

Tags: networking, network-programming, wireshark, libpcap, tcpdump

I am capturing packets using `libpcap`. I am calculating the payload size as given [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www.tcpdump.org/sniffex.c&ei=iGRlUP6WLIrW9QTXyIHQCw&usg=AFQjCNG06vPZLcb_gnMas5sM1m7uu5K53A&sig2=VKvPBo3Qicjw1cNg1Dn3QA)
`size_payload = ntohs(ip->ip_len) - (size_ip + size_tcp);`
Now, for a packet, `size_payload` is 1228, ethernet header is 14 bytes, IP header is 20 bytes, TCP header is 32 bytes. While `header.caplen` and `header.len` are 1514 bytes. Shouldn't `size_payload+size_ip+size_tcp+size_ethernet` be equal to `header.caplen`?
Also, when I dump the same packets using tcpdump, the capture length is shown as `1514`. Why do these differ? I expected `ntohs(ip->ip_len)` to be equal to `header.caplen` and `header.len`

**EDIT**
I expected `ntohs(ip->ip_len)` to be equal to `header.caplen` and `header.len`. But what I find is `ntohs(ip->ip_len) = 1280` and `header.caplen = header.len = 1514`

Comment: On what OS are you doing the capture?  And what do you mean by "Also, when I dump the same packets using tcpdump, the capture length is shown as 1514."?  You say that "differs", but if you say that `header.caplen` is 1514 in your program, and that tcpdump shows the "capture length" as 1514, that sounds as if they're reporting the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `caplen` says how much of the packet *may* be captured, not necessarily how much actually was.  You need to compare that value with the `len` field.

If `caplen >= len` you know that you should have the entire packet contents available.  Otherwise, the packet capture has been truncated.

Comment: In this case, `caplen` and `len` are equal (both 1514 bytes). I do have a big `SNAPLEN`. But `ip_len` is 1280 bytes.